# Welchem Zweck dient "sie" in "sie die Resultate aufheben"

Tags: pronoun

Kontext

> Auch die Art und Weise, wie die Gleichungen dieses Modells Vorhersagen
>   über die Welt machen, ist absurd kompliziert. Direkt angewandt, führen
>   sie zu unsinnigen Vorhersagen, bei denen sich jeder berechnete Wert
>   als unendlich groß erweist.

Sentence

> Um sinnvolle Resultate zu erhalten, muss
>   man sich vorstellen, dass die in sie eingehenden Parameter ebenfalls
>   unendlich groß sind, damit **sie** die absurden Resultate aufheben und
>   vernünftige Resultate ergeben.

Wenn „sie“ die Gleichungen ist, warum ist es nicht "von ihnen"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der Satz ist so zu verstehen:

> Um sinnvolle Resultate zu erhalten, muss man sich vorstellen, dass **die in sie eingehenden Parameter** ebenfalls unendlich groß sind, damit **sie** die absurden Resultate aufheben und vernünftige Resultate ergeben.

Sie refers to Parameter. The parameters will get rid of the absurd results. "of the aforementioned equations" / "der vorigen Gleichungen" is implied here, but not mentioned.

Comment: Ok, that doesn't help because I don't understand what the second sie is. Bolding the antecedent doesn't clear it up. I read "In order to get meaningful results, you have to imagine that the parameters going into the equation likewise are infinitely big, so the [insert strange sie here with no obvious meaning to me] absurd results are canceled out... Is sie supposed to indicate "out of the equations" like an indirect object?

Comment: Added more clarification

Comment: That last clause is giving a reason – *damit* –, and *sie* is its subject. *Damit* works just like *dass* in all other aspects. *Damit* may be replaced by *auf dass* with no change in meaning. Sometimes the *auf* is skipped, leaving a bare *dass* and the reader has to guess the type of clause from context.

Comment: @user5389726598465 There's no passive in the last part of the sentence, it's simply "so that _they_ [i.e. the parameters mentioned before] cancel out ..."

Comment: @DonHolgo Yes, clearly not passive. identical feminine acc/nom was forcing me to search for a subject that makes sense. Sie in the antecedent was erroneously stuck in my head as "equations"